# Suggest jquery image upload with client size resizing and Queued processing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, file-upload

I wants to do jquery image upload with client size resizing and Queued processing on my asp.net webpage.
I tried some online up-loader plugins, but either they are slow or crashes on mozila if i upload large sized file. Please suggest me any solution or plugin for this.

Comment: Tried google already?

Comment: not sure about resize but for others you can try cutewebui http://ajaxuploader.com/